# Why chrome is not shows .gif ajax loader image but firefox shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, google-chrome

In my project there is a mail sending scenario and it takes too much time to process. so i have added a ajax loading image. Code is given below:

```
$("#loadingmessage").hide();

$("#submit").click(function () {
    $("#loadingmessage").show();

 });
```

And HTML code is:

```
<div id="abc" >

    <div id="loadingmessage" style="z-index: 9999; width: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 28%;">
   <img src="~/Images/Bank/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly when using Mozilla Firfox(version:38.0.5) but not works well when using Google chrome(version 49.0.2623.87 m)

while using chrome, the image only shows just before the process ends, but i need to show the image when user click the 'send' button.
How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Are you making `synchronous`requests ? `async : false`

Comment: @RayonDabre yes, Should i need to change that?

Comment: Make `async : true` or just do not keep this option at all...

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks. it works now..